# Pseudopotential model to reproduce quantum statistics from ideal gas

Tags: homework-and-exercises, statistical-mechanics, ideal-gas

A pseudo-potential $V_{12}$ between every pair of particles in an ideal gas is to be constructed which will reproduce the effects of quantum statistics if the gas particles are bosonic in nature. A correct formula for this, in terms of the inter-particle distance $r_{12}$ and a mean distance $\lambda$, will be of the form $V₁₂ = -k_{B}T ln (1+e^{(-2\pi r_{12}^2/\lambda^2)})$.

I am trying to form the pseudopotential by trying to construct the approximate Hamiltonian but getting no way to construct the wave function for the wave gas. I am also confused about how to use the interparticle distance $r_{12}$ and mean distance $\lambda$ to get the pseudopotential. It will be helpful if a hint to the problem is provided.